# Unit testing InitializeComponent() for a partial Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, interface, partial-classes

I am new to C# and Unit testing and I have been trying to implement tests for the following constructor:

```
public Stepup()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Stepup is a partial class and inherits an Interface. How does one implement unit test for such a constructor? Also in addition to that, what are some ways to unit test a simple constructor with no parameters?

Comment: Stepup doesn't look as class nor method. If it should be a method (missing void return type) the only thing you can do is to check the state of your object modified by InitializeComponent.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The code here is for the Stepup Constructor. I have edited the question to be clear. Also how can I check the state of the object modified?

Comment: It is completely auto-generated code, both the constructor and the InitializeComponent() method.  If your unit test fails, you'll have to fix Visual Studio.  There's not a heckofalot of point to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a constructor runs, certain invariants about the constructed object should be true. You need to *specify* what those invariants are, and then *test* that they are true when the constructor finishes executing. The main point here is that you *do not* test in the internal implementation details of the constructor, only that whatever your specification says is true about the constructed objects is actually true.

For example:

```
class Circle {
    private readonly double radius;
    public double Radius { 
        get { 
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<double>() >= 0));             
            return this.radius;
        }
    }

    public Circle(double radius) { 
        Contract.Requires(radius >= 0);
        this.radius = radius; 
    }
}
```

Here, the invariant after the constructor finishes is that `Circle.Radius` returns the value for the constructor parameter `radius` that was passed in. This is the specification, and it can be tested.